# zabbix monitor disk on Windows

Tags: monitor, zabbix, health-monitoring

now ,I get the value from Zabbix Server.The value include IOPS,IO Response Time,and so on.But I want to monitor whether the value is in the range allowed.How to do it.
demo:
items [A]
name Avg Disk sec/Read Response Time
key perf_counter[\234(_Total)\208]
now new items [B] monitor items[A]'s Value, if Value < 12 ms items[B]'s Value is Good,else items[B]'s Value is bad.
In a word,i only want to monitor the disk io response time is healthy or not.

update:
items[A] : monitor windows disk
items[B] : another items is uesed to monitor items[A]'s Value
I want to show io health in charts,instead of setting the trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite get what's item "[B]", but in general, thresholds (or more complicated problem conditions) in Zabbix are specified using [triggers](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/triggers/expression).

For example, in your case the trigger expression could be `{host:perf_counter[\234(_Total)\208].last()}>12`. That is assuming your item holds data in ms. If other units are used, adjust the threshold accordingly.

This example uses the most simple trigger function, `last()`. See the [trigger function list](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions) in the Zabbix manual for an idea of other, more fancy trigger expressions you could construct.

Comment: items[A] : monitor windows disk ，items[B] : another items is uesed to monitor items[A]'s Value.I think you may not understand what I think.I want to show io health in charts,Instead of setting the trigger

Comment: Why do you need two items? You can view graph of the original item. Also note that items can't "monitor" values of other items - well, calculated items can reuse those values, but I'm not sure what benefit would that provide here.

Comment: Because I want to monitor windows disk and  know disk status health or not.Showing its value(disk status code) on the chart is more intuitive, 0 health 1 unhealthy